# calling a function from a class C++

Tags: c++, class, function

the header file is this:

```
#include "Lib110ct.h"
class Circle
{
protected:
    double mx, my, mdx, mdy, mradius;
public:
    Circle(){}
    Circle(double x,double y,double dx,double dy,double rad):mx(x),my(y),mdx(dx),mdy(dy),mradius(rad){}
    void setPos(double x, double y){mx=x;my=y;}
    void setDir(double dx, double dy){mdx=dx; mdy=dy;}
    void setRadius(double rad){mradius=rad;}
    double getX(){return mx;}
    double getY(){return my;}

    void draw(Turtle * t);
    void clear(Win110ct& win);
    void move();
    bool collides(Circle & c);
};

#include "shape.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)

    {
        Win110ct win;
        Turtle * t = win.getTurtle();
            Circle Circle;
            Circle.setPos(100, 300);
            Circle.setRadius(12);
            getX();
            getY();
            Circle.draw(t);

         return 0;
    }
```

The error message it's giving me is:

> C:\Users\Oluwaseun\Documents\110ct\challenge2\programming\programming\main.cpp|13|undefined reference to `Circle::draw(Turtle*)'|

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you defined `draw(Turtle*)`?

Comment: He's saying, you've declared a function `void draw(Turtle*)`, but you haven't shown code in the example where you define what the function does.

Comment: @OluwaseunTemitopeBamgboye: I mean where is the function body?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 1):

You need to **define**

```
void draw(Turtle * t);
```

Please take a look at: http://www.cprogramming.com/declare_vs_define.html

Basically, you define a function when you write the code for it:

```
void draw(Turtle* t) {  
    // code here
}
```